# Fiddler not capturing certain websites

Tags: ssl, fiddler

I am using fiddler version 4 and am unable to capture some websites like Facebook, google, gmail, yahoo; however, it captures some other websites correctly.

I checked the filters option and found that they use filters option "Unchecked" and also checked fiddler through its IP and its running correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's causes by missing https decryption.

There is a menu point to import the fiddler root certificate in the local certificate store.

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/TrustFiddlerRootCert

**How to:**

1. Click Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS.
2. Click the Decrypt HTTPS Traffic box.

[image]